# How do I select a different theme for both GNOME and Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have different GTK+ theme in Unity and Gnome Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63986/is-it-possible-to-have-different-gtk-theme-in-unity-and-gnome-shell)

I want ambiance to be the theme when I choose Ubuntu, and adiwwata to be the theme when I go into GNOME. I think it was like that after a clean install, but not anymore. Cant it be done...