# Can I automatically change Theme according to desktop environment?

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have different GTK+ theme in Unity and Gnome Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63986/is-it-possible-to-have-different-gtk-theme-in-unity-and-gnome-shell)

Since it is quite a bit of hassle to go into settings, then Appearance, then change the theme to Ambiance (for Unity) or Adwaita (for GNOME shell) - Is there an automated way of doing this, so If I choose GNOME shell at the Login screen, the Theme will automatically switch to Adwaita, and Ambiance with Unity.